# How is this sentence inverted or changed when the adverbal phrase **through every window** is moved at the beggining of the sentence?

Tags: inversion

I am a non-native English speaker and sometimes it is very hard to understand the way how inversion happens in sentences.

What inversion does happen with the first sentence below when *through every window* is moved to the beginning of the sentence?
And is the inversion a matter of a must or choice?

> Light is coming in through every window. I don't think I can sleep here.
>
> Through every window ***???***. I don't think I can sleep here.

Couple of my guesses are below.

*Through every window is light  coming. I don't think I can sleep here.*

*Through every window is coming light. I don't think I can sleep here.*

Any explanations will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Preposing an adjunct like "through every window" does not trigger subject-auxiliary inversion, so "Through every window light is coming in" is right.

Comment: @BillJ I am so grateful that you got my point and gave me a comment.  Thank you. Then, what are the cases like that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion? Can I ask you for some explanations about those?

Comment: @BillJ Then, is there no way to do inversion in the sentence with "Through every window" preposed to the beginning? Are All of "Through every window is light coming in.", "Through every window is coming in the light." wrong?

Comment: @BillJ But, as an example sentence that oppose your explanation, "Here comes the bus." is inverted sentence with an adverb preposed to the beginning of it. And in school, I might have been taught that "Here comes the bus." is wring and "Here the bus comes." is wrong. Would I ask you help me get out of this confusion?

Comment: I’ll answer your 3 questions in order. **Subject-auxiliary inversion** occurs with questions, for example _**Have you** done it?_; _**Did you** finish it?_. It also occurs when certain elements are put in front position. Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted, e.g., _Never **have I** felt so alone_ the inversion is triggered by the negative word “never”. And in _So bad **was the pain** that I fainted_, and _Only later **did I** realise my mistake_, the fronting of “so bad” and “only later” have triggered the inversion.

Comment: No, it is wrong to say *_Through every window is light coming in_ and *_Through every window is coming in the light_. There is no fronted element in either of those examples to trigger subject-auxiliary inversion. The subject and verb should remain **uninverted**: _Through every window **light is** coming in_. Preposing an adjunct (adverbial) does not trigger subject-auxiliary inversion.

Comment: _Here comes the bus_ does **not** oppose my explanation. It does **not** contain subject-auxiliary inversion, though it is a special kind of **subject-dependent** inversion – special because it is not replaceable in context by the non-inverted _The bus comes here_. The same applies to _There goes my last dollar_; it is not replaceable in context by _My last dollar goes there_.  It is important that you distinguish subject-auxiliary inversion and the kind of inversion that has preposing of adjuncts (adverbials)

Answer (score 1):

```
Through every window, light is coming in.
```

When you are bothered about inversion, first identify the main idea/clause in the sentence in question.

In your case, the main idea is *"Light is coming in"*. *"Through every window"* just adds more information to the main idea.

Then, put the secondary idea (or clause) in the beginning of the sentence with a comma at the end. That gives us the following :

> Through every window,

As the final step, add the main clause or the main idea of the sentence to the above and don't forget the preposition!

Finally, we have the inverted sentence.

> Through every window, light is coming in

---

**Is this a must or a choice?**

It is a choice.

If you want to make others feel that you are a student of literature, user inversion often ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere answer. If I may ask, is the comma there a must?

Comment: Yes it is a must. Look here for some explanation. If you still find it confusing,  do write a comment https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/

Comment: Putting an element before the subject of a clause when its basic position would be after the verb is called **preposing**, not inversion. In the OP's example, the phrase "through every window" has not been inverted, but simply preposed to the front of the clause before the verb instead of being in its normal position after the verb as in "Light is coming in through every window"